# How to hanlde PHP Exceptions properly

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to implement my own exception handling in my new PHP project, I have faced no errors yet but I fear that my architecture is not right, let me show you what I mean.

I'm currently implementing a system that can handle some types of files, writing them, deleting them, created them, etc, and of course, there are a lot of things that I need to be aware off, so many things can go wrong, so I made the following structure yet I feel I repeat myself too much.

So, I made this as my main Exception class that all of my custom Exceptions are gonna extend:

```php
abstract class PickleException extends Exception implements Throwable
{
    abstract protected function handle () : void;
}
```

And I made the following two exceptions which at the moment do the same thing

```php
class DuplicateFileException extends PickleException
{
    public function handle() : void
    {
        echo $this->getMessage();
    }
}

class InvalidCreationDirectoryException extends PickleException
{
    public function handle() : void
    {
        echo $this->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Now, let me show how the File System is organized.

```
    FileManager -- Interface

        FileSystem -- Abstract class (Parent)

            PHPManager -- Class (Child)

            YamlManager -- Class (Child)

            XMLManager -- Class (Child)
```

Now, I know that I can throw new Exceptions in any of those classes but the question relies on where do I Catch them?, so far, I have something like this...

```php
abstract class FileSystem implements FileManager
{
    /**
     * Creates an empty file based on the path, name and extension
     * given.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $extension
     * @throws DuplicateFileException
     * @throws InvalidCreationDirectoryException
     * @return void
     */
    final function makeEmptyFile (string $path, string $name, string $extension) : void
    {
        $file = "$path/$name.$extension";

        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            if (!mkdir($path, 0777, true)) {
                throw new InvalidCreationDirectoryException("Error: Impossible to create directory");
            }
        }

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            throw new DuplicateFileException("Warning: File already exists, aborting");
        }

        touch($file);
    }
}
```

In other words. Where is the right place to catch all of the exceptions that I'm throwing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one "right" place to catch Exceptions, and no one way to "handle" them.

Ideally you catch them at a place in the code where you can implement logic to address the cause, eg: retry, or handle the failure gracefully, eg: close connections and abort. There is seldom a one-size-fits-all solution.

Otherwise, *do not catch them*. Uncaught exceptions should bubble up to a global Exception handler and be treated as a fatal error. This is the only "general" case Exception handler, and PHP's default is a fatal error and a stack trace. You might want to customize this to log the exception to disk and present an "Oops, something went wrong." message to the user.

Blocks like:

```
try {} catch( \Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

or

```
try {} catch( \Exception $e ) {}
```

are the equivalent of turning it into an informational alert and ignoring it.

**TL;DR:** Unless you plan to do something meaningful, don't catch Exceptions at all.

Comment: I think i get what you mean, but, there is something I still find hard to understand, if must of the exceptions that Im gonna throw are not going to be handle then whats the point of making my custom exception classes, what am I gonna do with the methods that Im coding there if the exception class its not gonna be instantiated it, or is it?; For example, how can a framework like symfony or laravel can print some nice looking error when I make a mistake while using the framework?

Comment: Virtually all of my custom exceptions are simply `class FooException extends \Exception {}` or `class FooException extends ExceptionFamily {}` with the name and/or parentage being the sole items of importance. The name both signifies the cause of the exception, leading to code and error messages that are easier to understand, and allows for each exception to be caught/handled by a specific `catch` block _if necessary_. Consider that this is not just beneficial to you right now, but also to future implementors and/or maintainers of your code.

Comment: Speaking of future implementors/maintainers, the `final` keyword is the bane of their existence. You should avoid that without _exceedingly_ good reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I understand better now. Thank you!.